# How do I get the new REVTEX style for APS Journals?

Tags: revtex, versions

The style for REVTEX 4-1 does not match the style of the journal, or it does not have a style for newer journals such as Physical Review X or Physical Review Applied.  How do I get the right style?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 1):

All APS journals now have the same style.  REVTEX has been [updated to version 4-2](http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au/pub/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/revtex/doc/auguide/auguide4-2.pdf) to reflect this change.  Download the latest version to get the correct style.

Thank you to the REVTEX team for the much needed update.